# I'm just getting started with PythonCard...

Tags: python, pythoncard

So, I'm just getting started with PythonCard and I can't get the most basic app to work :S I'm trying to assign values in TextFields to variables on clicking a button; please see if you can understand what the problem is :D

My python main file:

```
from PythonCard import model

class register(model.Background):
    def on_register_mouseClick(self, event):
        title = self.components.title.text
        artist = self.components.artist.text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = model.Application(register)
    app.MainLoop()
```

My resources file:

```
{'type':'CustomDialog',
    'name':'Template',
    'title':'Dialog Template',
    'position':(125, 125),
    'size':(300, 181),
    'components': [

{'type':'TextField', 
    'name':'artist', 
    'position':(115, 48), 
     'text':'artist', 
},

{'type':'TextField', 
    'name':'title', 
    'position':(116, 15), 
    'text':'title', 
    },

{'type':'Button', 
    'id':5100, 
    'name':'register', 
    'position':(10, 35), 
    'default':1, 
    'label':'OK', 
},

] # end components
} # end CustomDialog
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 3):

You by mistake made a `CustomDialog` instead of an `Application`. To fix your problem just replace your rsrc file with this code:

```
{'application':{'type':'Application',
          'name':'Template',
    'backgrounds': [
    {'type':'Background',
          'name':'Application',
          'title':u'Application',
          'size':(300, 181),

         'components': [

{'type':'Button', 
    'name':'register', 
    'position':(10, 35), 
    'default':True, 
    'label':u'OK', 
    },

{'type':'TextField', 
    'name':'title', 
    'position':(116, 15), 
    'text':u'title', 
    },

{'type':'TextField', 
    'name':'artist', 
    'position':(115, 48), 
    'text':u'artist', 
    },

] # end components
} # end background
] # end backgrounds
} }
```